# How to find a specific node in xml file?

Tags: c#

I have a 4GB xml file which I read with console c#. Now I want to insert some data from it to database. The node "NameDetails" and its children I am looking for is located somewhere in the middle of the file. The code I wrote is not finding that node. In the case is throwing the error unexpected node
The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;

namespace DawJone_Lista
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string first_name = " ";
            string middle_name = "";
            string surname = "";
            string gender = "";
            string occ_title = "";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {

                conn.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DawJoneList;Data Source=NLBPRISHTINA\\SQLEXPRESS";

                conn.Open();



                using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("C:\\Users\\Aplikacionet\\PFA2_201802282200_F.xml"))
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("spInsertimiListes", conn);

                        if (reader.IsStartElement("NameDetails"))
                        {
                            first_name = " ";
                            middle_name = " ";
                            surname = " ";
                            gender = " ";
                            occ_title = " ";

                            while (reader.Read() && reader.IsStartElement())
                            {

                                switch (reader.Name)
                                    {

                                    case "FirstName":
                                            first_name = reader.ReadString();
                                            break;
                                        case "MiddleName":
                                            middle_name = reader.ReadString();
                                            break;
                                        case "Surname":
                                            surname = reader.ReadString();
                                            break;
                                        case "Gender":
                                            gender = reader.ReadString();
                                            break;
                                        case "OccTitle":
                                            occ_title = reader.ReadString();
                                            break;
                                default:

                                    throw new InvalidExpressionException("Unexpected tag");
                            }
                            }
                            reader.ReadEndElement();

                        }

                        insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", first_name);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("MiddleName", middle_name);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Surname", surname);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", gender);
                        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("OccTitle", occ_title);

                        if (!((first_name == " " && surname == " " && middle_name == " " && gender == " " && occ_title == " ")))
                        {
                            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }


                    while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("NameDetails")) ; // it will read next descendent of person
                }
                conn.Close();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

With the debug it is going from 
                        if (reader.IsStartElement("NameDetails")) to the insert command
Any help please!

Comment: And the error is....? Could you please edit your question and paste the full stacktrace?

Comment: Which error is thrown by which line of code?

Comment: One more thing: if you need to insert some data from the xml file, I'd recommend you to parse the file first and get the data you need BEFORE you open the database connection.

Comment: It is not throwing any error,just is not inserting data.From this row  if (reader.IsStartElement("NameDetails"))
                        { code going at the end to insert command

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code it will help work:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample
{
  public static void Main()
  {
     //Create the XmlDocument.
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load("books.xml");

     //Display all the book titles.
     XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("title");
     for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
     {   
         Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
     }  

  }
}
```

> XML FILE:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database -->
<bookstore>
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
  <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
<author>
  <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
  <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
</author>
<price>8.99</price>
</book>
<book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">
<title>The Confidence Man</title>
<author>
  <first-name>Herman</first-name>
  <last-name>Melville</last-name>
</author>
<price>11.99</price>
</book>
<book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">
<title>The Gorgias</title>
<author>
  <name>Plato</name>
</author>
<price>9.99</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Cant load the xml file because is too big

Comment: really..? i dont think that should be an issue please try again

Comment: I have tried it gets this error OutOfMemoryException

Comment: where exactly??

Comment: It comes to doc.Load("books.xml"); and then throws that error of no memory